# GAE: Backend instance hours used without backend

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am developing an online register for patients in a hospital using Python on GAE.
I have tried to use first backends and then modules to do some calculations.

For the moment I stoped them and deleted the backend instance. 
But there is still a high usage of Backend Instance Hours.

How can I control and stop this?

Comment: Did you check the graphs on dashboard in GAE admin console? Specifically see "Instances" graph (choose from dropdown). You will notice that there might be difference between "active" and "billed".

Comment: At the momment I haven't got a single instance and still every day the backend instance hours are going up to the qoatas (9 hours). I'm still developing on the localhost and the app is not used at all.